# ¿Es posible acceder a un valor en concreto de un dict_keys o dict_values en Python?

Tags: python, diccionarios

Si tengo un diccionario en Python y obtengo en un objeto tipo dict_keys sus claves o sus valores en un dict_values con keys() y values(), ¿puedo acceder como si fuera una lista o una tupla a una de sus posiciones?

No me funciona ninguna forma, ni las de acceso a diccionarios, ni a tuplas, ni listas.
Estos objetos son iterables, puesto que con un bucle, obtengo cada uno de esos valores.
Sin embargo, si quiero obtener solo 1 posición del índice, ¿cómo lo hago?

Lo único que se me ocurre, es transformar el dict_keys o dict_values a tupla o lista. Así si puedo hacer algo como esto:

```
diccionario[0]
```

Es solo saber si se puede acceder al índice individualmente sin bucles o sin transformar a lista tupla.

Comment: Los diccionarios asocian una clave con un valor. No son tuplas ni listas. Hablar del elemento en la posición 5 no tiene sentido ni utilidad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al margen de que tenga o no sentido, en python 3 no es posible porque tanto `.keys()` como `.values()` como `.items()` devuelven objetos de tipo `dict_keys` o  `dict_values` o `dict_items`, respectivamente y no listas.

Estos tipos implementan el protocolo "colección" (`Collection`), lo que significa que implementa los métodos apropiados para que puedas:

- Saber cuántos elementos hay (puedes hacer `len(diccionario.keys())`.
- Saber si un cierto valor está en la colección (puedes hacer `if "foo" in diccionario.keys()`)
- Iterar por los valores (puedes hacer `for k in diccionario.keys()`, o pasarlo como parámetro a un constructor de listas, como `list(diccionario.keys())`

Dicho de otro modo, el objeto de tipo `dict_keys` (o los otros que he mencionado al principio), es subclase de:

- `collections.abc.Sized` lo que permite aplicarles `len()`
- `collections.abc.Container` lo que permite encontrar elementos con `if x in ...`
- `collections.abc.Iterable` lo que permite iterar sobre ellos, ya sea en bucles `for` o en desempaquetados, o en cualquier contexto donde se espere un iterable (por ejemplo en el constructor `list()`.
- `collections.abc.Collection` que implica que es las tres cosas anteriores a la vez.

**Sin embargo** no implementan el protocolo "Secuencia" (es decir, no es subclase de `collections.abc.Sequence`) por lo que no implementa el método que te permita acceder a elementos del contenedor a través de un índice. Por eso no puedes usar `diccionario.items()[0]`.

Todo esto acerca de qué protocolos implementa se puede comprobar experimentalmente:

```
>>> a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> keys = a.keys()
>>> import collections.abc
>>> isinstance(keys, collections.abc.Sized)
True
>>> isinstance(keys, collections.abc.Container)
True
>>> isinstance(keys, collections.abc.Collection)
True
>>> isinstance(keys, collections.abc.Iterable)
True
>>> isinstance(keys, collections.abc.Sequence)
False
```

En Python 2 todo esto era diferente, ya que `dict.keys()` (y compañía) devolvían una lista, pero en Python 3 ya no es así.

La única forma de acceder por posición a un elemento particular es convertirlo antes en lista, si bien eso no tiene mucho sentido como te han explicado porque un diccionario es un tipo de datos "conceptualmente" sin orden. Es un mero "mapeo" de unos valores (las keys) a otros (los values), sin que haya que presuponer ninguna ordenación de las claves ni de los valores.

Comment: Me parece que los objetos de Python no son subclases de los objetos del modulo collections. Si no que los objetos del modulo collections personalizan el resultado de isinstance para que en lugar de averiguar si es una subclase, analizar si sigue ciertos protocolos.

Comment: Igual, no estoy seguro. He revisado el código fuente del modulo abc (la base de collections.abc) y la verdad casi todo viene de c++

Answer (score 2):

En resúmen, se puede acceder a un valor pero no se puede por su índice. Si querés acceder a su valor deberías escribir algo así:

```
valor_obtenido = diccionario["nombre_de_key"]
```

Lo que estás queriendo hacer es slicing sobre un diccionario el cuál no lo admite. Deberías pensar a un diccionario como una lista, en la cuál las keys equivalen al índice y el value al valor de un elemento de esa lista, ya que las keys tienen la finalidad de encontrar un valor dentro del elemento al igual que un índice en una lista.

También tené en cuenta que un diccionario se interpreta como un conjunto de elementos desordenados, entonces hacer algo como diccionario[0] debería devolvernos resultados inesperados. Aún así, no voy a recordar la versión de Python(3.x) pero en un momento ésto se normalizó y ahora mantienen un orden, el orden en que fueron creadas y/o agregados cada elemento o par clave-valor.